# extracting the team name from a list of people

Tags: excel, vba, validation, excel-formula, formulas

a task that i would've thought was simple but one that i cant figure out.

in column A i have about 600 rows filled with about 40 different names. these 40 people make up 3 different teams, what i need is the corresponding team that person belongs to in column B.

at the moment im  thinking a nested formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1="NAME1",A1="NAME2",),"TEAM1","")&IF(OR(A1="NAME3", A1="NAME4",),"TEAM2", "")&IF(OR(A1="NAME5", A1="NAME6",), "TEAM3", "")
```

ect  for all 40 names,

but this seems messy and not easily changeable if somebody moves teams or theres new people. is there a way to have a 3 columns with a list for each team and then a formula that search's the list, and  returns the corresponding team name in a cell? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your table:

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like i was over complicating it completely and as suggested a simple VLOOKUP was the answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Take the 600 entries, paste into new tab, make sure all are selected and go to Data ribbon --> remove duplicates to create your unique string of 40 names.

If you are taking the time to do a nested IF/OR statement, you are just as well to manually type the team names next to the relevant name.

Once done, you can do a VLOOKUP in column B of your original list to reference the unique string of 40 and bring back the correct team for the name in column A.

Comment: Hi, each month the names will be moved about so doing it manually isn't an option. There are also live formulas that will be dependent on the team name in column B, and a fair amount of VBA involved, so im trying to not include new tabs.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong but there will still need to be a degree of manual entry to maintain it if its moving monthly. So you'll either have to do it in a formula or as an external reference table.

If you want to stick with the IF/OR option, you could dynamically reference the names and teams by using cell references instead and then you only have to update cells as opposed to editing formula